# Creating an SQL trigger using a number variable

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm creating some triggers for a SQL database. I've successfully made two triggers which compare an INSERT to SYSDATE. For this third one I'm trying to make sure an inserted value isn't greater than 10. Below is the trigger and the test data to run it. I believe the issue is something to do with declaring the value rating.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_rating_ck
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF rating ON reviews
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
IF (NEW.rating > 10) THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Rating has to be between 1 and 10');
END IF;
END trig_rating_ck;
/

--TEST DATA
INSERT INTO reviews (review_id, reviewer_id, venue_id, description, rating, date_posted)
VALUES (seq_reviews.NEXTVAL, 10000,10000, 'THIS WAS GREAT', '11', '06-APR-2016');
```

Comment: What is the error you're receiving?

Comment: I would guess that you get an error when you create the trigger because you need to put a colon before `new` in `if (:new.rating > 10)`.  You might be getting an error running the `insert` statement as well because you're trying to insert a string into a date column rather than using a date literal or an explicit `to_date`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using declarative constraints for something like this, rather than triggers. I haven't worked with Oracle in a few years, but in SQL Server triggers can have big performance impacts, not to mention being more likely to cause bugs or let things slip through.

For this particular case you could simply use:

```
CONSTRAINT CHK_Reviews_rating CHECK (rating BETWEEN 0 AND 10)
```

That would just be part of your table declaration.

Triggers can also cause hidden business logic, which is a bad idea.

I don't know if you can customize the error in these situations, but your application should be able to see the error and handle it appropriately.